# Best way to release COM objects in C++/CLI wrapper

Tags: .net, com, c++-cli, com-interop

I want to create a C++/CLI wrapper that will help me translate some PIAs types to their unmanaged equivalents. This is a code sample:

```
void DoSomething(SomeInteropLibrary::InteropObject obj)
{
    IComInterface* pComInterface = NULL;
    IntPtr comInterfacePointer = Marshal::GetIUnknownForObject(obj);
    IUnknown* punkComInterface = static_cast<IUnknown*>(comInterfacePointer.ToPointer());
    punkComInterface->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IComInterface), (void**)&pComInterface);

    //Do something with pComInterface...

    pComInterface->Release();
    Marshal::Release(comInterfacePointer);
}
```

IComInterface is my COM interface, obj is an interop type from PIA that I generate from a type library.

I am interested in how to properly release the resources. Should I call `Marshal::Release`  for the second time, as it is written in the documentation for the method `Marshal::GetIUnknownForObject`, or can I just repeat `pComInterface->Release()`?

Comment: Look at the count returned by the Release, if it is 0 then you shouldn't need to.

Comment: No, you are already calling Marhal::Release().  Calling it again is a mistake, the MSDN article does *not* say you should release it twice.

Comment: I call pComInterface->Release for QueryInterface and call Marshal::Release for Marshal::GetIUnknownForObject.

Comment: I am pretty sure resources are released correctly in your code sample. They might be released correctly with just calling pComInterface->Release() twice, but it would be more logical to call Marshal.Release for each Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject call.